# Outputting prolog in Mac

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

I have a problem using prolog on a Mac, I figured out how to run it using SWI-Prolog but when I run it, it gives an error and does not give the expected output

**Expected output: homer, bart**

```
male(homer).
male(bart).
female(marge).
female(lisa).
female(maggie).

parent(homer, bart).
parent(homer, lisa).
parent(homer, maggie).
parent(marge, bart).
parent(marge, lisa).
parent(marge, maggie).

mother(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y), female(X).
father(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y), male(X).
son(X, Y) :- parent(Y, X), male(X).
daughter(X, Y) :- parent(Y, X), female(X).

?- male(X).
```

Here is the error I was speaking about earlier

```
Warning: /Users/[username]/Desktop/simpsons.pl:19:
Warning:    Singleton variables: [X]
true.
```

And instead of outputting **homer, bart** it outputs **true**

Comment: You need to enter `male(X).` interactively.

Comment: @false, isn't that done? `?- male(X).`

Comment: The `?- ` is the top level's prompt. And you type `male(X).`

Comment: @false so like this: `male(homer).
male(bart).
female(marge).
female(lisa).
female(maggie).

parent(homer, bart).
parent(homer, lisa).
parent(homer, maggie).
parent(marge, bart).
parent(marge, lisa).
parent(marge, maggie).

mother(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y), female(X).
father(X, Y) :- parent(X, Y), male(X).
son(X, Y) :- parent(Y, X), male(X).
daughter(X, Y) :- parent(Y, X), female(X).

male(X).` ?

Comment: You compile the rest (as you did before) and then loaded, you pose the query.

Answer (score 1):

When programming in Prolog, you put *definitions* and *queries* in different places. *Definitions* go into source files. *Queries* do *not* go into source files. You enter them while interacting with the Prolog system in something called the "toplevel" or "prompt" or "shell" or maybe "REPL" (read-eval-print loop).

For example, these are definitions:

```
male(homer).
male(bart).
female(marge).
female(lisa).
female(maggie).
```

You have put them in a source file called `simpsons.pl`. This is correct.

This is not a definition but a query:

```
?- male(X).
```

This does **not** go in a source file. Do **not** put it in `simpsons.pl`. Rather, you:

1. start your Prolog system
2. load the `simpsons.pl` file somehow
3. enter the query `male(X).` and observe answers

This video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6L7O7KiE-Q shows these steps with SWI-Prolog on a Mac.

If you are comfortable using a command line, you might also be able to do this simpler. For example, on my (Linux) machine, I can start SWI-Prolog with a command line argument naming a file to be loaded:

```
$ swipl simpsons.pl 
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.6.4)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.
Please run ?- license. for legal details.

For online help and background, visit http://www.swi-prolog.org
For built-in help, use ?- help(Topic). or ?- apropos(Word).

?-
```

See that `?-`? That is the prompt meaning that the toplevel is now waiting for your input. Here is where you enter your `male(X)` query. You can use <kbd>;</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> to cycle through the various answers:

```
?- male(X).
X = homer ;
X = bart.
```

Comment: BTW, where does this coloring come from?

Comment: StackOverflow recently changed to some new "smart" syntax highlighting that thinks everything is JavaScript, or something. It automatically colors code blocks (i.e., normal indented-by-four-spaces blocks) without having to do anything. And without providing an easy way to turn it off, as far as I can tell.